# Django nginx staticfiles 404

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I am trying to get my head around nginx serving Dockerized Django static files behind a https proxy.

I was trying to mostly follow this tutorial: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-lets-encrypt/

This was all working on my local machine so I moved to a remote server running at a real domain behind an https reverse-proxy.

I have a docker-compose.yml like this:

```yaml
  backend:
    container_name: backend
    build: ./backend
    command: gunicorn directorybackend.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    volumes:
      - ./backend/:/code/
      - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/code/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=mydomain.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8000
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=mydomain.com
    env_file:
      - ./env/.env.beta

  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    build: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/code/mediafiles
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - backend

  acme-companion:
    image: nginxproxy/acme-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-acme
    env_file:
      - ./env/.env.beta.proxy-companion
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
  acme:
```

There are also postgres services and a VUE frontend but they don't share volumes with the above.

I have a `default` file in vhost.d directory with the following directives:

```bash
location /static/ {
  alias /code/staticfiles/;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}

location /media/ {
  alias /code/mediafiles/;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

my nginx docker files is the following:

```bash
FROM jwilder/nginx-proxy:0.9
COPY vhost.d/default /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default
COPY custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/custom.conf
```

my Django settings.py:

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
```

I am collecting the files at backend boot and if I exec to either the `backend` or `nginx-proxy` services I can find my files at the correct location:

```
/code/staticfiles/... # all the files are here in the right place...
```

So I "assume" the volumes are correct.

`/vhosts.d/default` is also present and at the correct location when i log into the nginx service.

The HTTPS reverse-proxy works great. My backend is an API and calls to it work perfectly. I just have no static files for the admin area.

The static files however return a `404` error.

There are no errors being raised other than the 404 to load the static assets. What am I doing wrong?

MORE INFO:

I found this error in the nginx log:

```
2022/07/10 09:36:53 [error] 78#78: *4 open() "/home/backend/web/staticfiles/admin/js/nav_sidebar.js" failed (2: No such file or directory),
```

This is super confusing as I don't define that path - `/home/backend/web/staticfiles` -  anywhere I can find... changing the STATIC_ROOT in settings.py to match that path also does not work.

Does nginx define default paths anywhere?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by `the admin area`? Which URLs does the admin area correspond to?

Comment: all of them. I mean the Django admin. No static files - css/js etc are being served. The pages load without the static components.

Comment: Could you provide the complete `docker-compose.yaml` file?

Comment: Done. I left out the DB and VUE frontend services but, other than exposing the VHOSTS parameter for the lets encrypt proxty they dont share volumes with the above.

Comment: Also, are you setting the django settings correctly? What is the value of `BASE_DIR`? I think you have the files but django is not configured correctly.

Comment: Does django not get that from the docker context?

Comment: I'm not sure. Perhaps you can try by setting `STATIC_ROOT=/code/staticfiles/` for now just to see if that is the error.

Comment: It's the same error. I tried "staticfiles" as well.

Answer (score -1):

I had to destroy all the nginx-related images and volumes and rebuild them.

then it worked. Just rebuilding wasnt enough